# Settings.bundle vs NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults, settings.bundle

I have my settings.bundle configured to show 4 settings, which I want user to access/change. During application lifetime I have another couple of values, that i store in NSUserDefaults, but I'm not interested them to show up in the Settings.app. Is it possible at all that the number of values in settings.bundle will be different from actual number of key/value pairs, stored in the NSUserDefaults? What has to be done in order to manage it properly?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key/value pairs in your Settings bundle are managed by `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`, but there's nothing to stop you from adding your own keys and values to manage. They won't show up in the Settings screen for your app unless you add them to the bundle's property list.

Just register, store and retrieve user defaults the same way whether from your Settings bundle or not; there's nothing additional that needs to be done.

Comment: should I call registerDefaults each time in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions...? Or only the first time? I'm asking because a certain string setting second time returns nil. First time I register it with a default value, the second time, i get nil...

Comment: @Nava Carmon: Hmm, I've not faced issues calling `registerDefaults:` each time...

Comment: it happens if i don't change this value from the settings.app. Each time i reload my application, NSUserDefaults return nil for this specific value. Only after I change it in Settings.app it returns the changed value. How do I fix it? I synchronize my defaults after registering it and in applicationWillEnterBackground function?

Comment: If it's only affecting this one key, try deleting and creating one with a different name or something and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: I don't mind getting each time a value from the settings.bundle's Root.plist as long as it takes the right value after it's changed. Just a piece of small headache. Anyway thank you for making an order in this subject for me.

Comment: Calling -registerDefaults: will not cause changes on disk. It adds a volatile defaults domain (i.e. not synced to disk) to the search list. So, call it every time.